# Complex MySQL query with multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, select, multi-table

I have three tables in Mysql that are link together:

**Profile** (ID, Name, Stuff..)

**Contact**(ID, ProfileID,desc,Ord)

**Address**(ID,ProfileID, desc, Ord)

Now I need to select all profile from the profile table, with the `“desc”` field from Contact and Address where Ord = 1. (this is for a search function where in a table I’ll display the name, main contact info and main Address of a client.

I can currently do this with three separate SQL request:

```
SELECT Name, ID FROM Profile WHERE name=”bla”
```

Then in a foreach loop, I’ll run the other two requests:

```
SELECT ProfileID, desc FROM Contact WHERE ProfileID=MyProfileID AND Ord=1
SELECT ProfileID, desc FROM Address WHERE ProfileID=MyProfileID AND Ord=1
```

I know you can do multiple `SELECT` in one query, is there a way I could group all three `SELECT` into one query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to `JOIN` the tables on the `profile.id` and the `profileid` in the other tables.

If you are sure the `profileid` exists in all three tables, then you can use an `INNER JOIN`. The `INNER JOIN` returns matching rows in all of the tables:

```
select p.id,
  p.name,
  c.desc ContactDesc,
  a.desc AddressDesc
from profile p
inner join contact c
  on p.id = c.profileid
inner join address a
  on p.id = a.profileid
where p.name = 'bla'
  and c.ord = 1
  and a.ord = 1
```

If you are not sure that you will have matching rows, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select p.id,
  p.name,
  c.desc ContactDesc,
  a.desc AddressDesc
from profile p
left join contact c
  on p.id = c.profileid
  and c.ord = 1
left join address a
  on p.id = a.profileid
  and a.ord = 1
where p.name = 'bla'
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! 1 for the explanation and 2nd for the link, both your info and JW info help me get a better understanding of SQL... (I love understanding and learning the answer, not just copy paste!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This query below only selects column when an `ID` from `Profile` table has atleast one match on tables: `Contact` and `Address`. If one or both of them are *nullable*, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` because `LEFT JOIN` displays all records from the *Left-hand* side table regardless if it has a match on other tables or not.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.desc as BDESC,
        c.desc as CDESC
FROM    Profile a
        INNER JOIN Contact b
            ON a.ID = b.ProfileID
        INNER JOIN Address c
            ON a.ID = c.ProfileID
WHERE   b.ORD = 1 AND
        c.ORD = 1 AND
        a.Name = 'nameHERE'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` version:

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.desc as BDESC,
        c.desc as CDESC
FROM    Profile a
        INNER JOIN Contact b
            ON a.ID = b.ProfileID AND b.ORD = 1
        INNER JOIN Address c
            ON a.ID = c.ProfileID AND c.ORD = 1
WHERE   a.Name = 'nameHERE'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: HI JW, you can take a look at the comment left for bluefeet, the thank you also appliedto you!!!

Answer (score 0):

i have created [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/225fe3/2) as your requirement :

The query bellow will retrieve all matching records from the database.its retrieving profile id,name stufff and description of contact  tables

```
select p.id,p.name,p.stauff,c.descr,a.descr from profile as p
 inner join contact as c on c.profileid=p.id
 inner join address as a on a.profileid=p.id
 where p.name="bla" and c.ord=1 and a.ord=1
```